# Setting the contrast color for TextView and ImageView that is in Collapsing toolbar

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have an `ImageView` and `TextView` in `Collapsing Toolbar`. The image will be loaded from Server dynamically. The problem is when I set the color for `TextView` (white or black), its contradicting with the color of the image one way or another. As I am a beginner I don't know how to solve it. Could anyone help me with this?

**Announcement Activity**

```
public class AnnouncementDetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private TextView mTitle;
    private TextView mDescription;
    private ImageView image;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    private String mAnnouncementTitle;
    private String mAnnouncementDescription;

    private String mAnnounceImage;


    public GetAnnouncementTask mGetAnnouncement = null;

    private String DateString = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

    private static final String TAG = "AnnouncementDetailsActivity";

    public static final String TAG_ANNOUNCEMENT_LIST_FRAGMENT = "announcement_list_fragment";

    private CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(Color.rgb(38, 55, 98));

        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_announcement_details);

        mTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.announcement_title);
        mDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.announcement_image);


        collapsingToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.detail_collapse_toolbar);
        collapsingToolbar.setTitle(mAnnouncementTitle);

//
//        collapsingToolbar.setCollapsedTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));

        collapsingToolbar.setExpandedTitleColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));

        setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.detail_announcement_toolbar));

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        Intent intent = getIntent();


        if (null != intent) {
            mAnnouncementTitle = intent.getStringExtra("announceTitle");
            mAnnouncementDescription = intent.getStringExtra("announceDescription");
            mAnnounceImage = intent.getStringExtra("announceImage");

            mTitle.setText(mAnnouncementTitle);
            mDescription.setText(mAnnouncementDescription);
            new GetAnnouncementTask(image)
                    .execute(mAnnounceImage);
        }
    }


    public class GetAnnouncementTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {


        ImageView image;

        public GetAnnouncementTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.image = bmImage;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();


        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String url = urls[0];
            Bitmap mIcon = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(url.replaceAll(" ", "%20")).openStream();
                mIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            }
            return mIcon;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            image.setImageBitmap(result);
        }


    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        onBackPressed();

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific and post a bit of your code or an image to define precisely what you want to do ?

Comment: Yes I have uploaded my code..

Answer (score 2):

You can change color of `TextView` according to color of image (which image is in background of text). There is `Palette` and `Swatch` in Android, check [here](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/extracting-colors-to-a-palette-with-android-lollipop/) and [here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Dynamic-Color-using-Palettes) for tutorial